# session login is set to 1 but is not recognized on redirection

Tags: php, jquery, session

what is wrong here:

```
$('#btnlogin').click(function() {
    var uname = $('#inpuname').val().trim();
    var pass = $('#inpass').val().trim();
    $.post('ad-login-pro.php', {uname, pass}, function(data) {
        console.log(data); // result is 1
        if (data == 1) {location.href = 'ad-start.php';}
    });
});
```

**ad-login-pro.php**

```
$xuname = $_POST['uname'];
$xpass = $_POST['pass'];
$sql = "select status, uname, pass from users where uname = :auname and pass = :apass limit 1";
$st = $db->prepare($sql);
$st->execute([":auname" => $_POST['uname'], ":apass" => $_POST['pass']]);
$row = $st->fetch();
if ($row['uname'] == $xuname && $row['pass'] == $xpass) {
    $_SESSION['login'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['logstatus'] = $row['status'];
    echo $_SESSION['login'];
}
```

**ad-start.php**

```
if (!$_SESSION['login'] == 1) {header('location: ad-login.php');}
```

This line works, i.e. I'm returning to `ad-login.php`.

But it shouldn't work because `$_SESSION['login'] == 1`;

Any idea?

Comment: Could you provide more information, I cannot understand what you are trying to do...!

Comment: @WorstProgrammerIntheWorld, this is a standard login procedure, if username and pass are ok - go to another page. I cannot go to this page, always returning to `ad-login.php`

Comment: `!$_SESSION['login'] == 1` is not the same thing as `!(!$_SESSION['login'] == 1)`.  What is the value of `!$_SESSION['login']`?  Is it "truthy"?  What happens when it's compared to an integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using `session_start()`:

Example:

**ad-login-pro.php**

```
// At the very top of the page
session_start();


$xuname = $_POST['uname'];
$xpass = $_POST['pass'];
$sql = "select status, uname, pass from users where uname = :auname and pass = :apass limit 1";
$st = $db->prepare($sql);
$st->execute([":auname" => $_POST['uname'], ":apass" => $_POST['pass']]);
$row = $st->fetch();
if ($row['uname'] == $xuname && $row['pass'] == $xpass) {
    $_SESSION['login'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['logstatus'] = $row['status'];
    echo $_SESSION['login'];
}
```

**ad-start.php**

```
// At the very top of the page
session_start();

if (!$_SESSION['login'] == 1) {header('location: ad-login.php');}
```

documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php